# bower.json how to skip already installed packages

Tags: angularjs, bower, dependency-management

In my application, all the packages except Chart and angular-chart are already installed.

I need to install only these two.

*Question: How to skip the rest of the packages from being updated or downloaded again?*

```
{
  "name": "ui-chromeapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.23",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.11",
    "underscore": "~1.7.0",
    "jquery.easy-pie-chart": "~2.1.4",
    "sprintf": "~1.0.2",
    "jquery.scrollTo":"~2.1.1",
    "angular-translate":"~2.8.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files" : "~2.8.1",
    "Chart.js" : "1.0.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "Chart.js": "1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: While using `bower install` command no new packages / dependencies were installed. When using `bower update` new versions of your packages will be downloaded (depending on your bower.json configuration -> package version config). All in all, both commands do not install a package in the same package-version again. Whats your problem so?

Comment: If you specify the ~ in front of the front of the version, in that case, it matches the 1.2.32 version. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json. I don't want to update angular to 1.2.32. Hence when I run bower install, it should not update angular or other libs but only chart.  **Other option to handle this is to remove the ~ and ^ sign from all the entries in the bower.json**, but is there any proper way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: So why dont you aim an a specific version. Just remove `~` an `^` and you will be fine?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: I have handled in the same way but I was thinking if there exists any other way or not?  Thanks

Comment: Check your questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5465648/yogesh-sonawane?tab=questions =) Do you know how to mark a right answer? There is a "grey" tick near the upvote button on each answer. Just hit it =)

Comment: Cheers m8 =) ! Please also check your other questions and mark right answers in the futures. You will also recive more help because some users will check your profile / mark rate before helping. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** While using `bower install`command, after your ran it once before, no new packages / dependencies were installed. When using `bower update` new versions of your packages will be downloaded (depending on your bower.json configuration -> package version config). All in all, both commands do not install a package in the same package-version again.

Just remove the version option handlers and you wil be fine. It's not a issue, it's a nice behavior.

```
{
  "name": "ui-chromeapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.23",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.2.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.11",
    "underscore": "1.7.0",
    "jquery.easy-pie-chart": "2.1.4",
    "sprintf": "1.0.2",
    "jquery.scrollTo":"2.1.1",
    "angular-translate":"2.8.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files" : "2.8.1",
    "Chart.js" : "1.0.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "Chart.js": "1.0.1"
  }
}
```